# How to avoid low memory warning in ios while downloading large files

Tags: objective-c, nsoperationqueue

In my application I am downloading PDF files from a server. The files' total size is around 4GB.  To download all these files I am using NSOperationalQueues. While downloading files app is giving low memory warning and app is crashing. How can I resolve this issue?

```
NSOperationQueue *taskQueue ;

    int random = arc4random() ;
        NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:random], @"currentOperationKey", file, @"file", nil] ;
        NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(synchronizeFileInThread:) object:params] ;
        [operation addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"isFinished" options:0 context:nil];

        [taskQueue addOperation:operation] ;
```

Comment: 4GB file in a Phone ?

Comment: move the downloaded file to the document directory and maintain the URL to avoid in this case, and also post the code please to find where you made a mistake

Comment: Hi Spynet I am downloading all files to document directory only.

Comment: Hi GoodSp33d yes 4GB size pdf files into iPhone document directory only.

Comment: If you append downloaded data to a `NSData` will make app crash. 4GB is huge. Create a file and append via `NSFileHandle`

Comment: What is NSOperationalQueue?

Comment: Hi gnasher I edited my question with sample code.Can you please check once.

Comment: Hi trick14 I have been used NSFileHandle.

Comment: You haven't actually shown any of the relevant code. How are you reading the data from the server, and how are you writing it to the file? Most likely, you're simply leaking all of the memory you're allocating to hold the data coming from the server.